# How generate a view to have dynamic column( column need to be created by referring rows of a table)

Tags: mysql

I have two table A and B. A has all list fruit juice and its price, B has type of serve and the price offset for the same.

Table A example

| # id | name | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | lemon | 015.00 |
| 3 | pineapple | 015.00 |
| 4 | grapes | 015.00 |
| 5 | mosambi | 025.00 |
| 6 | orange | 025.00 |
| 7 | water melon | 018.00 |
| 8 | carrot | 035.00 |
| 9 | papaya | 018.00 |
| 10 | banana | 018.00 |
| 11 | custard apple | 015.00 |
| 12 | musk melon | 018.00 |
| 13 | mango | 025.00 |
| 14 | butter fruit | 020.00 |
| 15 | apple | 025.00 |

Table B example

| # id | serve_name | price_offset |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | small | 0.50 |
| 2 | regular | 1.00 |
| 3 | medium | 2.00 |
| 4 | large | 4.00 |

I want a view like

| # name | small serve | regular serve | medium serve | large serve |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| carrot | 17.5000 | 35.0000 | 70.0000 | 140.0000 |
| grapes | 7.5000 | 15.0000 | 30.0000 | 60.0000 |
| lemon | 7.5000 | 15.0000 | 30.0000 | 60.0000 |
| mosambi | 12.5000 | 25.0000 | 50.0000 | 100.0000 |
| orange | 12.5000 | 25.0000 | 50.0000 | 100.0000 |
| pineapple | 7.5000 | 15.0000 | 30.0000 | 60.0000 |
| water melon | 9.0000 | 18.0000 | 36.0000 | 72.0000 |

I want the current statement to dynamically add server type as column and calculate price for individual fruit juice, rather then me mentioning it manually.

```
 SELECT 
        f.name AS name,
        (select st.price_offset * f.price from serve_types st where st.serve_name = 'small') as "small serve",
        (select st.price_offset * f.price from serve_types st where st.serve_name = 'regular') as "regular serve",
        (select st.price_offset * f.price from serve_types st where st.serve_name = 'medium') as "medium serve",
        (select st.price_offset * f.price from serve_types st where st.serve_name = 'large') as "large serve"
    FROM
        fruits f
    WHERE
        (f.milkshakeable = 0)
```

Comment: Please, [**do not post images of data.**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question#285557). Edit your question and add sample data in text format. Also apply appropriate tags because MySQL <> SQL Server

Comment: MySQL <> SQL - please correct your tags.

Comment: Noway, output rowset structure must be static for a view. In MySQL at least... Use stored procedure with dynamic SQL instead.

Comment: @Akina could please refer some example to achieve the same. I guess i have to do 2 loop here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE generate_report ()
BEGIN
SELECT CONCAT('SELECT f.name AS name,',
              GROUP_CONCAT('\n(select st.price_offset * f.price ',
                           'from serve_types st where st.serve_name = ''',
                           serve_name,
                           ''') as `',
                           serve_name,
                           ' serve`' ORDER BY id),
              '\nFROM fruits f')
FROM serve_types
INTO @sql;
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DROP PREPARE stmt;
END
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=760354721da6e5cb748261e2312536f0

You may add SP parameters which sets some filterings (like `WHERE (f.milkshakeable = 0)` in your code) and modify generated SQL code accordingly.

Comment: Thanks very much @Akaina this what I was looking for . I have never seen procedure that generated statements!, thanks once again.